# extract matching rows from a matrix and average them and produce a new matrix

Tags: python, r, matrix, bioinformatics

I have two matrices which contain unique rows. Also, I have another matrix which doesn't have unique rows. I have to select unique rows from the second matrix with respect to the first matrix and if two rows have the same name then the value will have to be calculated as an average of two rows.

1ST MATRIX:
[Click To download the first Matrix](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QNN1sSuIvETA8BvfcusRvl7ICYDLtkgg/view?usp=sharing)

[FIRST MATRIX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRdfi.png)

2ND MATRIX:
[Click to download the second matrix](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WyDboi3wBPtFoLa2PuK49a0lNBynas-t/view?usp=sharing)

[SECOND MATRIX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFunH.png)

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(MAT)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(MAT, 20))`. (`MAT` is the name of each of your matrices.)

Comment: could you please send your mail

Comment: @RummanAnsari: we encourage question authors to put the necessary detail in the question, so the problem can be solved in public. This means that the assistance might benefit future readers too. Thus, we ask for a [mcve]. If it really is not possible to cut the problem down - a pretty rare case - then the question is probably not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: We know you have matrices with more than 5 genes but the purpose of cutting it down is helping you faster. So cut down your matrices to max. 5 genes per matrix which are the most important for you in the example. Also answer the other poster questions. Not answering looks a bit rude and I amuse you are not such a person.

Answer (score 0):

As OP does not provide full scriptcode used I can only provide a general answer related to a matrix (database, list, etc) itteration step:

```
...snippet... # all import and other processing scriptcode here...

x = matrix1
y = matrix2

count1    = 0  # matrix 1
count2    = 0  # matrix 2
count_dbl = 0  # summary of encountered doubles within both matrixes

for item1 in x:
    count1 +=1
    for item2 in y:
            count2 += 1
        if item1 == item2:
            ..do whatever you need to do here...
            count_dbl+=1

        else:
            ... do something else here...
            pass

 print ('validation check on items in matrix 1: %s - 2: %s. Doubles: %s' % (count1, count2, count_dbl)
```

Tip: item1 or 2 can be methods processing readline information from e.g. xml or excel files, etc.

Enjoy ;p